# XFS filesystem - failed to start load/save random seed

Tags: linux, centos

During an extract operation of a developer on a server where only one partition existed the server crashed. After the server was rebooted it gave the following errors:

failed to start load/save random seed

failed to start create static device modes in /dev
failed to start devcice wrapper event daemon

I've booted into livecd to check and repair the filesystem and when I run xfs repair, I get the following error: (See attached) [image]

I've attempted allocating more space to the filesystem to increase inodes in case this is relateded to the server not booting and not being able to repair it but as far as I can see resize is not possible for XFS if the filesystem is mounted.

Can anyone advise on a potential solution?